# Text values incorrectly displayed when applying XSLT Transformation

Tags: xml, xslt

Given the following Xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<ROOT>
<MessageHeader>
<MessageId>b4794b26-f7fc-438d-bbc2-b30a4fbf5cf9</MessageId>
<CorrelationId>04ce5131-68d9-498a-9d19-02b2a5295537</CorrelationId>
<MessageDateTime>2017-06-06T14:14:58</MessageDateTime>
<BatchId>2a55cd19-ee46-4b59-a94b-2814665aaa82</BatchId>
<MessageSubmissionTypeCode>SomeInfoToGoHere</MessageSubmissionTypeCode>
</MessageHeader>
<Trns>
  <RemitKey>0100001002961</RemitKey>
  <DATE>01/03/09</DATE>
  <ClientNo>00031824</ClientNo>
  <POLNOI>00031824*001</POLNOI>
  <CurrPolicyStatus>Active</CurrPolicyStatus>
  <PolicyProdType>Something</PolicyProdType>
  <ClientNameType>Individual</ClientNameType>
  <ClientName/>
  <IdNumberType>CompanyRegistration</IdNumberType>
  <IdNumber/>
  <Insurer>Some Insurer</Insurer>
  <InsurerNo>00061</InsurerNo>
  <AgentCode>0001</AgentCode>
  <AgentName>Some Agent</AgentName>
</Trns>
</ROOT>
```

And given the following XSL file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
  <xsl:template match="/">
    <TestProcess>
      <xsl:apply-templates />
    </TestProcess>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="Trns">
    <Process>
      <Key><xsl:value-of select=".//RemitKey"/></Key>
      <Date>
        <Submitted><xsl:value-of select=".//DATE"/></Submitted>
      </Date>
      <Policy>
        <PolicyNumber><xsl:value-of select=".//POLNOI"/></PolicyNumber>
        <Type><xsl:value-of select=".//PolicyProdType"/></Type>
      </Policy>
      <Client>
        <Type><xsl:value-of select=".//ClientNameType"/></Type>
        <Name><xsl:value-of select=".//ClientName"/></Name>
        <Identification>
          <Type><xsl:value-of select=".//IdNumberType"/></Type>
          <Number><xsl:value-of select=".//IdNumber"/></Number>
        </Identification>
      </Client>
      <Insurer>
        <Name><xsl:value-of select=".//Insurer"/></Name>
        <Code><xsl:value-of select=".//InsurerNo"/></Code>
      </Insurer>
    </Process>
  </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

I Am expecting a transformation of

```
<TestProcess>
<Process>
      <Key>0100001002961</Key>
      <Date>
         <Submitted>01/03/09</Submitted>
      </Date>
      <Policy>
         <PolicyNumber>00031824*001</PolicyNumber>
         <Type>Something</Type>
      </Policy>
      <Client>
         <Type>Individual</Type>
         <Name/>
         <Identification>
            <Type>CompanyRegistration</Type>
            <Number/>
         </Identification>
      </Client>
      <Insurer>
         <Name>Some Insurer</Name>
         <Code>00061</Code>
      </Insurer>
   </Process>       
</TestProcess>
```

However, the text values of the `<MessageHeader/>` tag is inserted right below the `<TestProcess/>` node:

```
<TestProcess>

b4794b26-f7fc-438d-bbc2-b30a4fbf5cf9
04ce5131-68d9-498a-9d19-02b2a5295537
2017-06-06T14:14:58
2a55cd19-ee46-4b59-a94b-2814665aaa82
SomeInfoToGoHere

<Process>
.
.
.
```

I want to totally exclude the `<MessageHeader/>` data from being rendered. What am I missing please?

Answer (score 0):

First of all I would replace your  `<xsl:template match="/">` for  `<xsl:template match="ROOT">`.

Then for your question you have 2 possible options:

**Option 1**

You can create an empty template for `MessageHeader`. So just add this line to your XSLT file:

```
<xsl:template match="MessageHeader"/>
```

This means that when it tries to apply `MessageHeader` template it just displays an empty string.

**Option 2**

In the `ROOT` just apply the templates for child elements which name is not `MessageHeader`:

```
<xsl:template match="ROOT">
    <TestProcess>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="*[not(local-name() = 'MessageHeader')]" />
    </TestProcess>
</xsl:template>
```

Answer (score 0):

Change this part:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <TestProcess>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </TestProcess>
</xsl:template>
```

to:

```
<xsl:template match="/">
    <TestProcess>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="ROOT/Trns"/>
    </TestProcess>
</xsl:template>
```

Otherwise you are applying templates to **all** elements that are children of the `/` root node (and recursively to their descendants) - and these are being handled by the [built-in template rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/xslt/#built-in-rule) that copy their text values to the output.

---

P.S. Using the descendant axis is highly inefficient and unnecessary in your case (at least in the given example). Instead of:

```
<xsl:value-of select=".//RemitKey"/>
```

use:

```
<xsl:value-of select="RemitKey"/>
```

and similarly for the other elements of `Trans`.

Answer (score 0):

```
    ***Run this code***
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:template match="/">
<TestProcess>
<xsl:call-template name="ajeet"/>
</TestProcess>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template name="ajeet" match="Trns">
<Process>
<Key><xsl:value-of select=".//RemitKey"/></Key>
<Date>
<Submitted><xsl:value-of select=".//DATE"/></Submitted>
</Date>
<Policy>
<PolicyNumber><xsl:value-of select=".//POLNOI"/></PolicyNumber>
<Type><xsl:value-of select=".//PolicyProdType"/></Type>
</Policy>
<Client>
<Type><xsl:value-of select=".//ClientNameType"/></Type>
<Name><xsl:value-of select=".//ClientName"/></Name>
<Identification>
<Type><xsl:value-of select=".//IdNumberType"/></Type>
<Number><xsl:value-of select=".//IdNumber"/></Number>
</Identification>
</Client>
<Insurer>
<Name><xsl:value-of select=".//Insurer"/></Name>
<Code><xsl:value-of select=".//InsurerNo"/></Code>
</Insurer>
</Process>
</xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: You are assuming there is only `Trans` in the input (and if so, you could have handled it in the main template without having to call a named template).